# Handlebars and Sendgrid (UX) Campaigns for Dummies needed

Tags: handlebars.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I have a campaign in Sendgrid, using the Marketing (Legacy) version.  I'm trying to use Handlebars to evaluate a custom field (GC_Bounceback_Code1).  If it contains a static dummy value (i.e. zzz-aaa), I want it to display nothing.  If it contains anything else, I want it to display the contents. The #equals helper I've used is below.  I've used it in a Campaign Code Module and in a Template Code Module. It just displays the code as HTML text.

```
{{#equals GC_Bounceback_Code1 "zzz-aaa"}}
""
{{else}}
[%GC_Bounceback_Code1%]
{{/equals}}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what the email looks like?

Answer (score 0):

i asked support about this very question. they responded with this:

Unfortunately, conditional statements are not supported by legacy Marketing Campaigns templates. Rather than utilize conditionals, you could achieve your use-case by creating two separate templates and using a Custom Field within your contacts to create segments based on that custom field. You could then create a segment to utilize with template 1 and a separate segment to utilize with template 2 based on the criteria within the custom field and send each respective segment the proper content within the template.